# Layout changing when running the app

Tags: ios

I've been trying for days to make one layout of my app to work well, and after days of learning and mistakes I still can't get the table cell layout to look how I want it to be.
This is how my cell .xib looks like in the editor:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEr3r.png

And this is how my app looks like when running with suggested constraints:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiK1f.png

Why is that? How I can find my mistake and make the layout like it supposed to be, in the view?

Comment: Quick look - you've got yellow triangles, warnings, it means there are some issues in your layout, try to fix them by clicking on this triangles. Usually if you add suggested constraints, XCode doesn't complain that way

Comment: and sometimes it's easiest to get rid of ALL of the constraints and start again, rather than trying to fix things.  Always aim for as few constraints as possible - keep it simple and it will work really well

Comment: sometimes it is useful to set constaints manually by Ctrl-drag

Comment: @Russell: What works well usually is getting rid of ALL constraints, moving things where you want them, and then adding the constraint back, exactly as you want them.

Comment: As @schmidt9 said, the yellow triangles tell you directly that your constraints and the positions of your views in the layout don't agree.

Comment: @gnasher - absolutely.  That's certainly what I thought I had said!  It's what I meant :-)

Answer (score 0):

Suggested constraints are rarely what I actually wanted to see.

For each label with fixed text, lock the horizontal and vertical positions either to the view or to the next adjacent item.

For imageViews, choose the size you want and lock the height and width.

For labels that you will be dynamically changing the text on, pick a size that will hold the longest string and lock the width.  You'll need a vertical position constraint.

Answer (score 0):

You have many options to simplify your layout.
you can use the stakview or create a static UITableView and insert your component inside the cells and enter the Constraint. excellent tutorial http://www.runtimecrash.com/2015/09/17/exploring-uistackview/